# Accessing spring bean using context.lookup()?

Tags: spring, javabeans, lookup

I am new to spring and am trying to access a bean from my code.
Bean:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="beanid" class="org.apache.xbean.spring.jndi.DefaultContext">
         <property name="entries">
             <map>
                 <entry key="dummykey" value="dummyval">
                     <map>
                         <entry key="mykey">
                         </entry>
                     </map>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
       ........
```

I want to access the "dummyval" value.
when I use this code snippet, it gives me the map inside the dummykey entry. But I am not sure how to see the "dummyval"  value.

```
objBean = context.lookup("dummykey");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map entry has one key and one value. You're trying to have two values (dummyval and the map specified as a sub-element of the entry) in the same entry. That doesn't make sense, and Spring seems to use the sub-element and to ignore the value attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use the values inside the map only if some value in the code matches the dummyval. Do I have to use a separate entry for storing the dummyval then? or is there any alternative?

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: your answer here pointed me in the right direction. Thank you. I created a new entry